# How can we implement a impedance analyzer using arm m4f micro-controller?

Tags: arm

I need to measure the impedance of a composite material (in Giga ohms). How can I implement a device using ARM M4F micro-controller which can measure the impedance by giving a frequency sweep of 1Hz to 10MHz to the material and measure the impedance at each point of frequency?

Comment: Sounds like you know what you need to do, frequency sweep and measure. This is probably a) too broad a question, and b) better suited elsewhere such as ee.se

Comment: I am new to micro-controller programming, looking for steps or guidance in implementing this device.